# Uncaught ReferenceError: Alpine is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, alpine.js

Using Alpine with Laravel Vite is not working as expected. I'm getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Alpine is not defined

My app.js file:

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

Alpine.start();

window.Alpine = Alpine; // this should make Alpine globally accessible, right?
```

Including the app.js file in the head with: `@vite('resources/js/app.js')`

Then, when trying to use Alpine I placed the following script on the page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        console.log('alpine loaded') // this works so the event listener is called
        console.log(Alpine) // Uncaught ReferenceError: Alpine is not defined
    });
</script>
```

When opening the developer console and typing `Alpine` the object does actually exist. Any ideas on why Alpine isn't available in the global scope?

Comment: depending where you placed that code and the `@vite`, it could be possible the js script is run first and then `@vite` (download and load the file) so you don't have `Alpine` available, share where are you placing both parts please

Comment: `@vite` is included in the head, and the script tag is included just before closing the body.

Comment: after the page loaded, if you manually do `window.Alpine` or `Alpine` on the browser javascript console, does it show up or is it still `undefined`?

Answer (score 3):

You should do it like that.

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();

Then add @vite('resources/js/app.js') in the header of your blade file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).